# Finding all paths between a set of vertices in a DAG

Tags: graphs, dag

Given a  graph `G= (V, E)` that is:

1. directed,
2. acyclic,
3. non-weighted,
4. may have more than one edge between two vertices (thus, source and destination are not enough to determine an edge).

And given a set of vertices, let's  call them `vSet`; that contains a vertex `vRoot`; I need to find **ALL** paths `pSet` between `vSet` elements respecting the following:

1. any vertex that appears as a source for some path in `pSet` must be reachable from vRoot.
2. any path in `pSet` must has its source and destination from `vSet`, and must not contain any other vertex of `vSet`.

I've developed an algorithm similar to BFS, that starts from `vRoot` (according to 1 above),  grow each of the current paths with one edge per an iteration until it reaches another vertex `v1` of `vSet`; then store this reaching path and start growing new set of paths staring from `v1`.

Here is a pseudo code

```
output = ∅;
maxLengthPaths = ∅;
1. add all edges that vRoot is there source to maxLengthPaths
2. while size(maxlengthpaths) != ∅ do
  (a) paths := ∅;
  (b) extendedPaths := ∅;
  (c) foreach path p in maxLengthPaths do
    i. if (destination of p in vSet)
      1. add p to output 
      2. for each edge e that destination of p is its source
        A. add e to extendedPaths
    ii. else
      1. add p to paths
    iii. for path p1 in paths 
      1. for each edge that destination of p1  is its source
        A. extend p1 by a edge and add it to extendedPaths
  (d) maxLengthPaths = extendedPaths
```

Here are my questions:
1. Is this the best way to achieve my task?
2. I was trying to figure out its time complexity; I found that its exponential of pow(maxNumberOfOutGoingEdgesFormAVertex, maxLengthPath). Is this really the complexity?

Answer (score 4):

Any algorithm for your problem will have to take exponential time in the worst case.  However, if you're willing to live with this, there is a straightforward recursive algorithm to solve your problem.  Details below.

Generalizing a little bit, your problem is essentially the following:

**Input:** a dag $G=(V,E)$, three sets $S_0,S_1,S_2 \subseteq V$ of vertices

**Output:** the set of all paths that start some element of $S_0$, end at some element of $S_1$, and all of whose intermediate vertices are from $S_2$

To see the relationship to your problem statement, let $S_0$ be the set of vertices that are reachable from `vRoot` and also contained in `vSet`; let $S_1$ be `vSet`; and let $S_2$ be the complement of `vSet`.

There is no efficient algorithm for this problem, because in the worst case there could be exponentially many such paths.  Therefore, any algorithm to print all such paths will necessarily have to take exponential time, in the worst case.  Of course you could build algorithms that are efficient on some inputs, but no algorithm will be efficient on all possible inputs.

However if you are willing to live with this limitation, here is an approach you could use.  Basically, it's easy to come up with a recursive algorithm for this problem:

- Compute the set $S_0$ of vertices that are reachable from `vRoot` and are contained in `vSet`.  This can be found in linear time using DFS or BFS.  You can also compute $S_1$ and $S_2$ in linear time.
- Enumerate all paths of the desired form recursively.  We will build a procedure $F$ so that, for a vertex $v \in V$, $F(v)$ returns the set of all paths that start at vertex $v$ and end at some vertex in $S_1$ and where all other nodes (the intermediate nodes) are all within $S_2$.  You can compute $F$ via a simple recursive procedure:

  - For each $w \in S_2$ such that there is an edge $(v,w) \in E$, compute $F(w)$.
  - Now we can return $$F(v) = B(v) \cup B'(v) \cup \{v@p : w \in S_2, (v,w) \in E, p \in F(w)\},$$

    where $v@p$ denotes the path that starts at $v$, goes to $w$, and then follows the path $p$; and where $B(v),B'(v)$ are defined as follows:

    - if $v \in S_1$, then $B(v)$ is a singleton set containing the path of length 0 that starts at $v$ and stops there; if $v \notin S_1$, then $B(v)$ is the empty set.
    - $B'(v) = \{v \to w : w \in S_1, (v,w) \in E\}$.
- Finally, calculate $F(v)$ for each $v \in S_0$ and output the union of all of those paths.
- For better performance, I recommend that you use memoization to avoid ever calculating $F(v)$ more than once for any particular vertex $v$.

This immediately gives you a recursive algorithm that solves your problem, and whose running time is linear in the size of the graph plus the size of the desired output.  In other words, this algorithm is about as efficient as you could possibly hope for, given the problem statement.

Comment: thank you for this effort. However, I think that you misunderstand my question; 1- the root r is an element of R, 2- any path between two elements of S may contain multiple edges that do connect vertices from S, only the source and destination of the whole path (i.e. not each individual edge) have to be from S, 3- each path of the output must not have any vertices of S except for its source and destination.

Comment: @MedianHilal, thank you for the comments.  I've corrected my answer accordingly.  This should now meet all your requirements.

Comment: Thank you again. However, I want to point out some things, regarding my original problem: 1- Please note that your suppose about S0 and S1 is not precise, because they are the same set, i.e. there is no such explicit differentiation made between sources and destinations, one node can be both a source and a destination for two paths of my output -2- Please note that root is an element of of this set of nodes, so paths from root to any vertex of this set have to be computed, it's not just an issue of reachability.

Comment: Regarding your solution: 1- Your algorithm combines iterations with recursive; however it's similar to DFS, isn't it? -2- Actually, I cannot understand how would it be linear with size of the graph! It's linear with size of the output, but not the graph! Consider a simple (even extreme) of three vertices v1, v2, v3 and six edges e1,...,e6 where the first three edges connect v1 and v2, and the second three connect v2 and v3. Thus, we have 3*3 = 9 paths, e1e4, e1e5, e1e6, e2e4,...,e3e6 . Well, this has a exponential growth that cannot not linear with our graph size that have 3 v and six e.

Comment: I may think of a worst complexity of two components as I state in my question, which are max connectivity of an vertex, which is the max number of outgoing edges, and the max length path between two vertices, this.

Comment: @MedianHilal,  1- My algorithm works fine even if $S_0=S_1$.  I'm solving a more general problem.  2- I don't know what you mean.  1- Yes.  2- If $|G| is the size of the graph and $|L|$ is the size of the output, its running time is $O(|G|+|L|)$.

Comment: thank you again. However, are you sure you got my point about in the example of 3 vertices and 6 edges? Absolutely there are 9 paths, consider more extreme scenarios, the number of possible paths is horribly growing, it's may be even similar to compute possible combinations over some scenarios! Thanks

Comment: @MedianHilal, yes, I got that.  That's why I wrote in my answer that the number of paths might be exponential.  The running time is $O(|G|+|L|)$, where $|L|$ is the length of the output, i.e., the number of paths -- so $|L|$ can be exponential in the size of the graph.  The running time is linear in the length of the output, which can be exponential in the size of the input.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that. Now I got it :-)

Comment: I've put nearly 2 weeks into trying to derive this algorithm (or something very similar to it). Should we ever meet in person, D.W., I owe you a beer. +1